# PCB thermal via design for qfn package

Tags: pcb

How can I claculate how much via is required to dissipate a given amount of heat energy, for example my smd device case tmperature in datasheets says 80C, I used nearly 20C12 via 16 nos, but still the device is over heating, please let me kwow if there any calculation is there for via calculation for thermal pad.

Comment: See: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/26783/how-do-i-determine-the-area-of-copper-needed-on-a-pcb-to-provide-adequate-heatsi/26791#26791

Answer (score 2):

Follow the IC recommended heatsink or supply enough info on heat source and sink in your question. Vias are not sinks, rather they are heat pipes to a heat sink.